# Formula which show the Leaves data into months view

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a attendance module in the Google Sheets where i have one problem to present the data from one sheet to another. Currnetly i am using the `INDEX` `MATCH` function which is not working accurately.

I want to populate the Data according to each date and whenever the months changes then data should be change accordinly.

I have multiple employees which `Leaves` are of different types i want them to populate for the whole month.

```
    =ArrayFormula(XLOOKUP(1,(D$7>=Leaves!$D:$D)*($AJ$6<=Leaves!$E:$E)*(Leaves!$B:$B=$C8),Leaves!$I:$I,""
))
```

I have attached a google sheets which may explain better what i want to achieve. Your help will be much appreciated.

[SheetLink](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ETJksQvjkDR4UmpTNhP7fkwR9tPoRx8gmQxwkQyWgww/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added solution to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ETJksQvjkDR4UmpTNhP7fkwR9tPoRx8gmQxwkQyWgww/edit#gid=569407331). Please do test it out.

`=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(C8:C21),COUNTA(D7:AH7),LAMBDA(r,c,IFNA(FILTER(Leaves!I:I,Leaves!B:B=INDEX(C8:C21,r),Leaves!D:D<=INDEX(D7:AH7,,c),Leaves!E:E>=INDEX(D7:AH7,,c)))))`

-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer i appreciate the help. But this formula should be dynamic so it can work on any range instead of `D7:AH7` if i run this on shorter range it gives an error for rest of the empty names. There is one more problem it also gives an error if date column is empty like September has 30 days so it gives an error on 31 day

Comment: And i am looking for a simple solution which i can understand so later if i want to make changes i woulb be able to change. But i don't think i am able to change this one if needed.

Comment: I've tested out too and can't find these problems you're referring to. If you narrow D7:AH7 it works fine. The first two values of MAKEARRAY are the dimensions, amount of rows and columns. You can change those values to be as flexible as you need. You need a flexible amount of columns? Change the second value to refer a cell in which you have that amount. Need to include all potential employees? Change C8:C21 with C8:C

Comment: Then she/he's finding the values through applying filters, more or less the same way you've done in your XLOOKUP. It's quite difficult to find a simpler solution, since you want it to expand in both directions

Comment: Sorry It didnt work out for you. Hoping someone else would pitch in with another solution...

Comment: I got your formula and its working well as @Martin expained it very well. Can you please let me know just one more thing because i am confused with that. The above formula only catch the single month data instead of all months?

Comment: well it specifically looks into the date(s) you have in row 7

Comment: Thank you very much for being so nice actually i had mistake in the sheet. formula was working perfectly since you posted. Thanks once again.